# How to change values in a given column based on a condition and put those new values in a new column? (New information added)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, replace

I have a pandas dataframe called trade_lanes that shows an output below:

| Departure Country | Arrival Country |
| --- | --- |
| Malaysia | Poland |
| Germany | USA |
| Germany | Cameroon |
| Argentina | Vietnam |
| Algeria | Slovakia |
| China | Vietnam |
| Denmark | Singapore |

What I would like to do is create 2 new columns depending on the country: "Departure Region" and "Arrival Region" in the dataframe trade_lanes such that it looks like this as the output:

| Departure Region | Departure Country | Arrival Region | Arrival Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APAC | Malaysia | NECE | Poland |
| NECE | Germany | AMERICAS | USA |
| NECE | Germany | WEMEA | Cameroon |
| AMERICAS | Argentina | APAC | Viet Nam |
| WEMEA | Algeria | NECE | Slovakia |
| APAC | China | APAC | Vietnam |
| NECE | Denmark | APAC | Japan |
| Others | Tonga | APAC | Indonesia |

I have been working around for loops to go about this but I think I'm getting the flow processes wrong and because there's a condition where a country is tagged to region, it makes it even more complicated. Also note that, I believe I **need** to use a For-if-elif-else loop because there are countries in which I would label them as "Others" if the countries do not fall in the scope of regions.

I was thinking of duplicating "Departure Country" and "Arrival Country" columns and then replace it manually but I am pretty sure there's an easier way to do it using for loop.

This was what I attempted:

```
for elements in range(len(trade_lane)):
    
    apac = {"AUSTRALIA": "APAC", "BANGLADESH": "APAC", 
                  "CHINA": "APAC", "HONG KONG": "APAC",
                  "INDIA": "APAC", "INDONESIA": "APAC",
                  "JAPAN": "APAC", "MALAYSIA": "APAC",
                  "MALAYSIA": "APAC", "NEW ZEALAND": "APAC",
                     "SINGAPORE": "APAC", "KOREA": "APAC",
                    "TAIWAN": "APAC", "THAILAND": "APAC", "VIET NAM": "APAC"}

    nece = {"BELGIUM": "NECE", "CZECH REPUBLIC": "NECE",
                  "DENMARK": "NECE", "GERMANY": "NECE", "HUNGARY": "NECE",
                  "LUXEMBOURG": "NECE", "NETHERLANDS": "NECE",
                  "NORWAY": "NECE", "POLAND": "NECE", "ROMANIA": "NECE",
                  "SLOVAKIA": "NECE", "SWEDEN": "NECE", "TURKEY": "NECE"}
    
    wemea = {"ALGERIA": "WEMEA", "BAHRAIN": "WEMEA", 
                   "CAMEROON": "WEMEA", "CHAD": "WEMEA", "FRANCE": "WEMEA",
                   "GREECE": "WEMEA", "IRISH REPUBLIC": "WEMEA",
                   "ITALY": "WEMEA", "MOROCCO": "WEMEA",
                   "PORTUGAL": "WEMEA", "QATAR": "WEMEA",
                   "SAUDI ARABIA": "WEMEA", "SOUTH AFRICA": "WEMEA",
                   "SPAIN": "WEMEA", "TUNISIA": "WEMEA", "UGANDA": "WEMEA",
                   "UNITED ARAB EMIRATES": "WEMEA", "UNITED KINDGOM":"WEMEA"}
    
    americas = {"ARGENTINA": "AMERICAS", "BRAZIL": "AMERICAS",
                      "CANADA": "AMERICAS", "CHILE": "AMERICAS",
                      "COLOMBIA": "AMERICAS", "MEXICO": "AMERICAS",
                      "PERU": "AMERICAS", "UNITED STATES": "AMERICAS"}
    
    for x,y in apac.items():
        trade_lane["Departure Region"].values = trade_lane["Departure Country"].values[elements].replace(x,y)
        
trade_lane
```

However I get a KeyError: 'Departure Region'

Comment: The error you are getting is because you are trying to access the property 'values' of trade_lane["Departure Region"], but that column doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your dataframe trade lanes is called df:

```py
all_regions = {**apac, **nece, **wemea, **americas} # merge your dictionaries into one
df['Departure Region'] = df['Departure Country'].map(all_regions) #map countries to regions
df['Departure Region'] = df['Departure Region'].fillna('Others') #If any country not found in the map
```

You can do the same process for 'Arrival region'.

A for-loop version of this could be:

```
all_regions = {**apac, **nece, **wemea, **americas} # merge your dictionaries into one

temp = []
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Departure Country'] in all_regions:
        temp.append(all_regions[row['Departure Country']])
   #else if: # add here corner cases.
   #    do something 
    else:
        temp.append('Others')

df['Departure Region'] = temp
```

Comment: it doesn't create a column properly. the output I got doesn't tag the country properly to its region. Is there a for loop with else-if-elif method for this?

Comment: can you specify which country isn't being tagged properly? I'd recommend you add that case in your example so the solution considers it.

Comment: added a for loop version. hope this works

Comment: the initial solution simply copies values in departure country into departure region column. 

However, your new solution seems to work now! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP. I'VE SPENT DAYS TRYING TO FIND THIS SOLUTION. I wouldn't have posted this question on Stack Overflow if I hadn't tried all possible ways to the best of my ability. T_T